# Flutter Web URL Navigation Strategy Conflict with Riverpod: Reloading Page Leads to 404 Not Found

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm currently working on a Flutter Web application where I aim to implement URL navigation using the strategy outlined in the official Flutter documentation: URL Navigation Strategies. However, I suspect that there might be conflicts with my usage of Riverpod within the application.

The specific problem I'm encountering is that when I attempt to reload a page, I consistently encounter a "404 Not Found" error. I believe this issue may stem from the interplay between my URL navigation setup and the Riverpod state management library.

This is the code I've employed to set up the URL navigation strategy:

```
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

All this in the development environment.

I've included the necessary dependencies for Flutter Web in my project's SDK.

I've tried other packages like the outdated `setPathUrlStrategy();`.

Comment: Use browser's developer tools > Network tab to see exactly which URL gives the 404 and update question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure riverpod is not at fault.. but you might want to add your route configuration, if you hare having problems with routing..  and give more details about what requests your browser is sending.. Did you check out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/127462 - ie. is your `initialRoute` starting with a `/`?